# Question on Limits from Spivak Calculus {Ch 5 Question 31}

Tags: limits

Question goes as follows:
Suppose that $\lim_{x\to {a-}}f(x)<\lim_{x\to {a+}}f(x)$. Prove that there is some $m \gt0$ such that $f(x)\lt f(y)$ whenever $x \lt a \lt y$ and $|x-a|\lt m$ and $|y-a|\lt m$. Is the converse true?

What I tried:
I could picture this situation on graph and prove it but i do not know how to prove it rigorously. Also, I don't understand how to find answer to the second question. All I did is try to think of a function which does not satisfy the converse but could not come up with one, so I concluded the converse is also true. I'm sure this method is not right for finding the answer. Can anyone please provide me the correct solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $l = \lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x)$, $L = \lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f(x)$ and $k = \frac{l+L}{2}$. By hypothesis, we have $l < k < L$.

By definition of the limits, it exists $\delta^-$ such that for $x- \delta^- < x < a$ you have $f(x) < k$. And $\delta^+$ such that for $a < y < a + \delta^+$ we have $k < f(y)$. Denote $\delta = \min (\delta^-, \delta^+)$

Now for $x < a < y$, $\vert x-a \vert, \vert y -a \vert < \delta$ we have indeed $f(x)<k < f(y)$.

**The converse is not true.**

Obviously we'll have $l \le L$. However, we can have the equality $l = L$ for example for continuous maps at $a$.